# Multinomial Logit with mlogit and Yogurt Data

Tags: r, multinomial-distribution, logit

I am using the [mlogit package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlogit/index.html) in R to estimate a choice model, I started with the famous [Yogurt dataset](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/Ecdat/html/Yogurt.html).

```
library(mlogit)

data(Yogurt)
names(Yogurt)

Yogdata <- mlogit.data(Yogurt, choice = "choice", shape = "wide", varying = c(2:9), 
                       sep=".")

Yog1 <- mlogit(choice ~ feat+price , data = Yogdata)

summary(Yog1)
phat      <- Yog1$probabilities
Yname     <-colnames(phat)
Y1hat     <- max.col(phat)
Y1hatname <- Yname[Y1hat]

preds = predict(Yog1,newdata=Yogdata)
preds[100:120,]
Yogurt[100:120,c('choice')]
```

The output `preds` includes probabilities that sum up to 1 for each row.

```
         dannon     hiland    weight   yoplait
 [1,] 0.3881972 0.03053851 0.2200040 0.3612603
 [2,] 0.6834572 0.01580043 0.1138286 0.1869137
 [3,] 0.4136804 0.03137184 0.2344462 0.3205015
 [4,] 0.4136804 0.03137184 0.2344462 0.3205015
 [5,] 0.4136804 0.03137184 0.2344462 0.3205015
 [6,] 0.4136804 0.03137184 0.2344462 0.3205015
 [7,] 0.4136804 0.03137184 0.2344462 0.3205015
 [8,] 0.4136804 0.03137184 0.2344462 0.3205015

 [1] dannon  dannon  yoplait yoplait dannon  dannon  dannon  yoplait dannon 
[10] dannon  yoplait yoplait dannon  dannon  dannon  dannon  dannon  dannon 
[19] dannon  dannon  dannon
```

The choice would be the highest probability in each row. Would this be correct? When I compare this choice against real choices coming from Yogurt, for the same rows, I see matches are not too great. Is there a way to improve this model? Is this the right way to judge the success of this model?